# X "poses" or "provides" or "presents" challenges to Y

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the correct (better) way to say that Y will be challenged by multiple aspects of X:

X poses new challeges to Y

X provides new challenges to Y

X presents new challenges to Y

Any other suggestions ...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Poses** and **presents** can share the definition of "asks, sets, or introduces". Both of those are good words for this sentence.

**Provides** has a positive connotation (whereas the other two are more neutral), which makes it seem less fitting when you're discussing "challenges".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I see the difference now. Is there another verb to use here having a negative connotation?

Comment: Your good observation (that 'poses' & 'presents' are more neutral and therefore more fitting) is confirmed (to my satisfaction) by running an American English "[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams)" search using the following phrase: (*_VERB new challenges,provides new challenges,offers new challenges) (without the parenthesis). It does show the positive "provides" (& "offers" for another positive one), but they're at the bottom as your answer would suggest.  It also suggests another "neutral to perhaps slightly positive one" ("brought/brings") between 'presents' & 'poses.'  cc: @ImadJAMIL

Comment: @ImadJAMIL No, I can't think of a good alternative to use here for "poses" or "presents" that has a negative connotation. But if you want to convey a sense of frustration with these new challenges, I would maybe try "creates", which is another neutral synonym for "poses/presents", but has a kind of more forceful sound that might help add meaning to the sentence.